# Get stripe form data from with php

Tags: php, forms, stripe-payments

I want to create a custom form (for name, email, adress, etc.) with stripe, but I don't know how to get the form data, that can be used in my php file. Few years back it was possible to send everything easlily with the post method,but now I can't figure out how it is possible to customize the given form.

The JS code:

```
fetch("../create.php", {
 method: "POST",
 headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
 body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
 })
.then(function(result) {
  return result.json();
 })
.then(function(data) {
  var elements = stripe.elements();

var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
card.mount("#card-element");

card.on("change", function (event) {
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = event.empty;
  document.querySelector("#card-error").textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
});

var form = document.getElementById("payment-form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    const name = form.querySelector('#name');
  payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
 });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test:my_api_key');

function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
   return 1400;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
  $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

  $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($json_obj->items),
  'currency' => 'usd',
  ]);

  $output = [
  'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
  ];

  echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
  http_response_code(500);
  echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <form id="payment-form">
  <div id="card-element"><!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element--></div>
  <button id="submit">
    <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
    <span id="button-text">Pay now</span>
  </button>
  <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
  <p class="result-message hidden">
    Payment succeeded, see the result in your
    <a href="" target="_blank">Stripe dashboard.</a> Refresh the page to pay again.
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With async payment flows you need to handle more of the payment flow client-side to support things like SCA and 3D Secure.  Usually this means sending information to your server with async JavaScript calls rather than an HTML form.

You mentioned form fields like name, email, etc. in your question, but the code you shared doesn't contain anything like that, so it's difficult to provide an answer specific to your situation.  Instead I can provide some basic guidance...

If you have an HTML element on your page like this:

```html
<input id="email" type="email">
```

You can get the value of that input using JavaScript like this:

```js
var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
```

Then you can send it to your server async using code like this:

```js
fetch("server.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email
    })
}).then(/*...*/);
```

Then, in `server.php` you can do something like this to get the email value:

```php
<?php
$rawBody = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$body = json_decode($body, true);
$email = $body['email'];
```

You should of course add in error handling, server-side input validation, etc., but those are the basic building blocks.